# Lava roof not glowing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the bottom of a lava brick not glow?

I made a glass-and-lava roof on my house, but the lava appears dull and low-lit. A glass-and-lava floor, in another base, is much brighter.

Is there a way to get a lava roof to glow downwards?

**Edit**
Added some screenshots to show the problem.

[image: Roof]
[image: Floor]

Comment: You have appeared to have already completely answered your question. What do you need help with, exactly?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Clarified the question.

Comment: Perhaps you're roof is too high up? How many blocks tall is the room?

Comment: From your screenshots, I am wondering: is the problem that it doesn't emit light from the bottom, or is it that the bottom lava texture is not as bright?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I believe this to be the case. Looking at the walls, it appears there is the same amount of light coming from both sides.

Comment: Hi high are your walls exactly? Also, you do realise that having wood that close to lava probably isn't the best idea?

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie They are 2 blocks tall, and the lava is enclosed by stone and glass, it never actually touches the wood.

Comment: Yes, but in another question I answered about how close lava has to be to wood to start a fire, it was confirmed that it can be anywhere around the lava (source or not) even when it is diagonally connected.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie Well it was just a demo I built, not my actual base anyhow :)

Answer (score 6):

Lava does light up blocks below.  At least in 1.6 it does.  I made a small room completely blocked off from light and made a lava ceiling.  Above the lava is more blocks to ensure no external light is getting in.

[image]

I know that sometimes lighting gets messed up.  When I see black areas that should be lit, I put a torch down and remove it.  This seems to reset the lighting in that area.  Maybe try that and see if it fixes it?

Comment: I added some screenshots to clarify the question :)

Comment: @ERJ Ah, I think you mean the Texture.  Based on the screenshots here, I think the bottom texture might be darker than the top.  However, light will go out in all possible  directions from the lava block.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a bug. 1.6.2 works perfectly, and I know it has worked since the full release of minecraft (I have a world where the roof is lava, and it is cool...). Since everyone else is uploading pictures, I will to:

[image: Before after shot]

As you can see, the results are amazing. If that doesn't convince you, I'm not sure what will. amazing/10 photoshop skills aswell.

These are real screen shots. It isn't just a black square/rectangle placed over half the image. That is what it was like with obsidian below the glass.

Also my brightness was "moody". You may want to try and turn up your brightness to the maximum settings.

Comment: Just so the image doesn't cause confusion, even though the obsidian "looks" darker (due to being black/dark blue) than a lighter material, for example, stone bricks, the actual _light level_ value which determines whether enemies spawn or not is [calculated in a different way](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Lighting).

Comment: I used obsidian to demonstrate how it lit up naturally "darker" blocks.

Comment: I added some screenshots to clarify the question :)

Answer (score 2):

As the two existing answers have pointed out, a lava/glass ceiling should work, as lava has a light level of 15.

If it's not working, perhaps it is because you are down close to the bottom of the world, causing "void fog" to seem like it's dark. However, even though it looks dark, as long as the light level is 8 or above, nothing should spawn.

Remember though, if you use the lava/glass ceiling, you cannot have a room height of more than 6 blocks, or else the floor will be dark enough for things to spawn.